# Elasticsearch nest search multiple field values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am combining search and aggregations in my page.

The aggregations work fine when combined from different groups, but are not working correctly when i choose multiple aggregations from the same group.

for example... if i have 2 aggregations showing on the default page load say

aggA (1000)
aggB (400)

Choosing aggA correctly shows 1000 results... and aggB will correspondingly be reduced to say 50

However when i then click an aggB instead of getting the expected 50 results i get 400... hence my search results are not combining the 2 search query values but just acting on the last one in my list that is passed to elasticsearch.

My code:

```
objESResults = client.Search<ESContent>(s => s
        .Query(a =>
        {
            return
            a.Match(m => m.OnField("_all").Query(m_strSearchQuery).Operator(Operator.And))                
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.ContentType).Terms(m_lstSelectedContentType))
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.Sectors).Terms(m_lstSelectedSector))
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.Companies).Terms(m_lstSelectedCompany))
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.ContentRegions).Terms(m_lstSelectedContentRegion))
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.Author).Terms(m_lstSelectedAuthor))
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.Country).Terms(m_lstSelectedCountry))
            && a.TermsDescriptor(t => t.OnField(f => f.Columns).Terms(m_lstSelectedColumns))
            && a.Range(t => t.OnField(f => f.EntryDate).GreaterOrEquals(DateFrom));
        }
```

m_lstSelectedSector will contain the values for aggA and aggB but is there some way to  get elastic search to do an AND on them rather than just search on the last value in the list. ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding `.minimumshouldmatch(100%)` to each query.